# oAuth2.0 for both private and public resources

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to implement oAuth2.0 protocol in my web application for communication between server and a mobile app (both the resource server and the mobile client are owned by the same company).
Given the high level of trust between server and client I decided to implement Resource Owner Password Credentials flow, and here is my problem: some resources are not reserved (such as product listings, product details), so they not need an access token for a resource owner; but other resources are private (user's products wishlist and the like).
So for non-private resources I need to only authenticate the client (the mobile app) while for private resources I need to authenticate both the client and resource owner.
Considering that a user may navigate the app and sign-in in a second moment, do I have to split the protocol flow in 2 steps? If so, how to handle tokens storage?

I hope I was clear enough.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Note that the OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials grant (or flow) is not so much about trust between client and Resource Server but about a high degree of trust between the Authorization Server and the client since the client "sees" the password that it sends to the Authorization Server (it never sends it to the Resource Server).

In your case you could obtain and use 2 access tokens obtained through different flows:

1. an access token that is obtained by the client itself through a Client Credentials grant, used against the public resources
2. an access token that is obtained from a Resource Owner through a Resource Owner Passwrod Credentials grant, used against the private resources on behalf of the Resource Owner

That is all assuming that you want to protect your "public" resources. If that they are really public, you would not even protect it and would not have to send any access token, so 1. is not even required.